# Choose files to stage of a new directory with magit

Tags: magit, git

If you create a new directory, its files won't show up with **magit-status**, only the new directory is in the list of *Untracked items*.

Currently I have to **magit-stage-item** the new directory and then remove unwanted files from the stage area.

Is there any way to choose which files to stage from a new directory?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Run:

```
git config status.showUntrackedFiles all
```

or if you want to enable this in all repositories:

```
git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles all
```

and refresh the status buffer. Initially you will still only see directories which contain untracked files, not the files themselves. But these directory sections can now be expanded using <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

One possible disadvantage of using `status.showUntrackedFiles all` is [a chance of slow performance](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables), when using Git directly - Magit actually counteracts that.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this setting globally? How can I add it to my ~/.gitconfig file?

Comment: @krystalcode: Try `git config --global` to modify global settings.

Comment: is it possible to limit how many files are shown per each directory? If I am selectivelly staging and ignoring fles from a directory, this could allow staging large directories a few files at a time without slowing down rendering too much

Comment: No there is no support for that. In this special case you probably have to resort to doing some of the work outside of Magit.

Comment: Is there some way to get magit to run `git status --untracked-files` (or other functional equivalent) to get this setting, so that I don't have to set it on my repository (or globally) in a way that effects command-line usage?  I like the default behavior in the command-line, because I can then just run ls on the relevant directories if/when I want to, instead of getting lots of noisy output always... but in magit, I want a way of expanding things within that context.  ?

Comment: Yes, `magit-git-global-arguments`.